# How to know if a project is checked out or checked in from PSI?

Tags: project-server, project-server-2007, psi

How to know if a project is checked out or checked in from PSI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Project.ReadProjectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.project.readprojectlist.aspx) or [Project.ReadProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.project.readproject.aspx).

This will return a ProjectDataTable in [ProjectDataSet.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.projectdataset.project.aspx). From there you can check the [PROJ_CHECKOUTBY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.projectdataset.projectdatatable.proj_checkoutbycolumn.aspx) and [PROJ_CHECKOUTDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.projectdataset.projectdatatable.proj_checkoutdatecolumn.aspx) columns.

Comment: If I only know the project name, How can I get the project information.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509731/if-i-only-know-a-projects-name-how-do-i-get-its-guid