# If I only know a project's name how do I get its GUID?

Tags: project-server, project-server-2007, psi

The PSI has various methods such as ReadProject that only take a project GUID and not its name.

If I only have a project's name, how do I retrieve its GUID for use in other PSI methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ReadProjectStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.project.readprojectstatus.aspx). It allows passing through an empty GUID but a project name to retrieve this information.